# Why is Excel temporarily locking us out of non-locked sheets/cells?

Tags: excel

I am having trouble diagnosing this problem we in our office have begun to experience since... upgrading(???)... to Excel 2016.

We cannot recreate the issue on command; we are not sure what causes it. I am not even sure what to Google (list below)! We'll be working in a sheet, all is normal, moving from cell to cell or whatever... then at some point, moving from one typical cell to the next, suddenly, the sheet just... stops letting us use it. It just stops letting us make changes and acts strange.

Here are the symptoms:

- Can edit some cells, but the changes will "vanish" when you leave the cell.
- Can not click on all cells. The selector with just not highlight them.
- Can not add or remove filters, or sort.
- Can not Copy or Paste.
- Can not delete any cells that can be highlighted.

This can happen to us on a variety of sheets and *none* of them have "protection" or sheet locking of *any kind whatsoever*. Zero, zilch, nada. These sheets are NOT "Locked for Editing". And I've looked at my co-workers keyboards to ensure that something silly like Num or Scroll lock wasn't causing the problem; they're not enabled.

One solution which I've found *sometimes* seems to fix the problem, is to switch sheets. That's it! Sheet1 not responding and treating you like you're locked out? Switch to Sheet2 (just click on it) then switch back to Sheet1. Fixed! Now the cells just... work again. The selector works again. Editing works again, just from switching from one sheet back to another. Well... sometimes.

Other times that does nothing, and then we have to save and reopen the sheet, and it works fine without any other changes. It is very confusing that, without even doing anything besides reopening it, that it works again.

These are a *few* examples of the stuff I've tried Googling over the last few weeks (I don't think I need to provide the complete list here... all searches have returned nothing useful, only articles talking about how to Lock and Unlock your sheet properly, which isn't this):

- excel 2016 locks from editing
- excel 2016 locks while working
- excel 2016 locked for editing not locked
- excel 2016 can't edit until switch sheets

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known problem in excel 2016, Especially if you have windows 10.  It looks like you need to keep resetting it like you have been doing but it is annoying.

If you try to disable "hardware graphics acceleration" in options menu, that should fix the issue and you would not have to keep switching between sheets.

Comment: Yes we do all have Windows 10. I've had a co-worker who is dealing with this a lot change that setting. Do we know ways to trigger the bad behavior to test it? Otherwise I guess we'll have to wait through today, maybe next week, to see if the problem still shows up. Thanks, I'll report back if it works. :)

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites The only way to test it is just by using excel which I'm sure you will be doing so it really is just a waiting game to see if it occurs again.  It sounded like the problem was frequent for you and your co-workers so hopefully you can see a difference right away.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: The issue came up again for my co-worker. There is nothing unusual that I can see being done differently than normal. It looks like it should be working just fine, but only allows her one change on the sheet before she has to click back and forth to unlock it again.